# How to move special characters and numbers to the end when sorting using `localCompare`?

Tags: javascript, sorting

### The problem statement

I want to sort words alphabetically, but move numbers and special characters to the end of the list

For example, sorting:

```
zdx
9or
abc
a=c
```

should result in:

```
abc
a=c
zdx
9or
```

As you can see `localeCompare` doesn't work like that. It treats numbers and symbols as "smaller" than characters.

```js
const items = ['zdx', '9or', 'abc', 'a=c']
items.sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
console.log(items)
```

### What I have tried:

Replacing all non-letters with a char code higher than `z`

```js
const items = ['zdx', '9or', 'abc', 'a=c']
const last = String.fromCharCode('z'.charCodeAt(0) + 1)
items.sort((a, b) => a.replace(/[^a-z]/g, last).localeCompare(b.replace(/[^a-z]/g, last)))
console.log(items)
```

Replacing all non-letters with a `z` works fine but not always

```js
const items = ['zdx', '9or', 'abc', 'a=c', '9ac', 'zac']
const last = 'z'
items.sort((a, b) => a.replace(/[^a-z]/g, last).localeCompare(b.replace(/[^a-z]/g, last)))
console.log(items)
```

Comment: Wouldn't it just work if instead of `last` you just use the letter `z`?

Comment: @Reyno hi :) Unfortunately not. I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

You last `z` replacement didn't work because `z..` is still before `za..`

You're not limited to `a-z`, `sort()` uses [UTF-16 unit values](https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm), set `last` to something higher then `z` (or you could use `zzzzzz`)

```
const last = String.fromCharCode(0xFFFF);
```

```js
const items = ['zdx', '9or', 'abc', 'a=c', '9ac', 'zac']
const last = String.fromCharCode(0xFFFF);
items.sort((a, b) => a.replace(/[^a-z]/g, last).localeCompare(b.replace(/[^a-z]/g, last)))
console.log(items)
```

```json
[
  "abc",
  "a=c",
  "zac",
  "zdx",
  "9ac",
  "9or"
]
```